# Flatten Mercurial Revision Chain

Tags: mercurial

I have a long sequence of mercurial changes (each with only a single parent), some of which conflict with each other and others which do not. I'm trying to "flatten" that sequence of changes such that the resulting tree has the minimum depth, without triggering manual merges.

I have a simple bash script which seems to do this. It works by continually trying to rebase revisions on top of their grandparent revision. However, this approach is incredibly slow for long revision chains.

```
#!/bin/bash

for rev in $(hg l --template "{node}" | egrep --only-matching "[0-9a-f]+")
do
  while :
  do
    # Attempt to rebase the revision on top of its grandparent.
    hg rebase -s $rev -d "first(parents(parents($rev)))"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      # Find the updated revision after the rebase.
      rev=$(hg log --hidden --rev "$rev" | egrep rewritten | egrep --only-matching "[0-9]{4}[:][0-9a-z]+")
    else
      hg rebase --abort
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

Is there a faster way to do something similar?

Comment: 1. If you have *linear* history `(parents(parents($rev)))` is overcomplexity, you can use just `$rev^2`

Comment: 2. Instead of LINE/2 final depth you can get only 4 (TBT!) changesets at final stage, if you'll use `--collapse` in rebase

3. Can't see any sense for egreping (especially inside cycle) and $rev-manipulation

Comment: Thanks for the $rev^2 pointer. It looks like "--collapse" combines multiple commits, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. I don't want the change the number of commits, only how those commits are arranged.

Comment: OK, at least you can kill (from my POV) all egreps and save some time

Comment: How do I remove the $rev manipulation? Whenever a revision is rebased its revision number changes and I need to get the new revision number (to try rebase the new revision onto its new grandparent)? Or is there something special about `--collapse` which changes this behavior?

Comment: You touch every revision **only once** with rebase, as I think, and after rebase have to process known-before parent

Comment: At least try this way, from top to bottom without egrep and repeating chain of rebase with new list of changesets after reaching root. It have to be faster

Comment: If you could add a simple tree diagram `A-B-C-...` as an example of that you are trying to accomplish that would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

1. Linear history can't contain "conflicting" changes (in case of overlapping changes *latest win all*)
2. You have at least two ways (if we'll forget about MQ) for squashing commits for **any size of commit-history**

- [histedit](https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/tutorials/squash-commits.html)
- [Fold command](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#example-6-fold-multiple-changesets-together-into-one) from Evolve extension

Comment: Maybe "conflicting" is the wrong terminology here. I suppose I mean "overlapping" then. If rev1 modifies file1.txt and rev2 builds upon those modifications to file1.txt, I don't want those revisions to end up as siblings. I want rev2 to stay as a child of rev1.w

Comment: I also don't want to squah any commits. I want every commit to stay independent, I just want to change the way those commits are arranged in the graph.

Comment: @LorenVanSpronsen - I can't see your history, but in common case you can get big (AFAICS) headache with changesets child relationships, *IF* your changesets modify more than single file. In degenerated case "1 commit - 1 file" you can use `hg log FILE -T "{node|short}\n"` for each file in repo and rebase affected changeset into separate subtree of history